# Convert From Geopoint To String

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i have google Maps and when the user touch any point in the map 
i will create marker and put it in this touch place
and take the whole 'Geopoint' for this marker
and it all work fine.
this is my code, that pt will take the coordinate.

```
 GeoPoint markerGP
 markerGP = pt;
```

But i want to convert the markerGp to string

any one can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: as per you question "But i want to convert the markerGp to string" do markerGP.toString();.. or you should ask more precise qustion.

Comment: every class extending Object have the toString() method. If it does not satisfy you, you can always subclass GeoPoint and ovveride toString()... you should be more precise in what you need to achieve

Comment: i already doing .ToString but when i put it in Toast so i can check. the Toast it did not appear so i assume the error is in String.`String var = Gpmarker.tostring(); Toast.makeText(getBaseContxt(),var,Toast.length...)`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with [String.valueOf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method for this. If markerGP is your `GeoPoint` means, try to do like below -

```
GeoPoint markerGP;
String result = String.valueOf(marketGP);
```

And, use this `result` anywhere you need.

Comment: it did not show me any Toast!! i put the toast after i add new marker. am i right?

Comment: First, place a breakpoint on your `markerGP` and check whethere the latitude is coming or not. After, that do this one `String result = String.valueOf(marketGP);` in this case, test if the result will provide you the string value of your geopoint. And, let me know

Comment: Hmm, try with that type also.

Comment: i am trying to do this `
String result = String.valueOf(marketGP); Toast.makeText(getBaseContxt(),var,Toast.length...).show();` but no Toast Appear

Answer (score 1):

```
long lat = markerGP.getLatitude();
long lng = markerGP.getLongitude();

String strLat = String.valueof(lat);
String strLng = String.valueof(lng);
```